# ImportError: cannot import name 'InputDevice' - Evdev

Tags: python, joystick, gamepad, evdev

I installed evdev on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with `sudo -H pip install evdev`.
The installation went normally and I ran `python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/evdev/evtest.py` to see if it was working. Everything was fine.

The issue is that when executing this Python code:

```
from evdev import InputDevice, categorize, ecodes
gamepad = InputDevice('/dev/input/js0')
print(gamepad)
for event in gamepad.read_loop():
  print(categorize(event)
```

I get this error as an answer:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "evdev1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from evdev import InputDevice, categorize, ecodes
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/evdev.py", line 2, in <module>
    from evdev import InputDevice, categorize, ecodes
ImportError: cannot import name 'InputDevice'
```

But when I execute `from evdev import InputDevice, categorize, ecodes` on a python shell it seems to work.
What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this?

Thankfully, Davi.

Answer (score 1):

It's written in your error traceback: You have a file called `evdev1.py` and a file `evdev.py` in your working directory. An `from evdev import ...` in `evdev1.py` would try to import from the file `"/home/pi/Desktop/evdev.py"` - which is also a module.

That's why calling `from evdev import ...` from within another working directory works.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little confusing, but there are old and new methods of accessing gamepads/joysticks in linux.  The older joydev shows devices as "js*" while the newer evdev shows them as "event*"

If you're using evdev, you need to use the event path starting with "/dev/input/event" instead of the one starting with "/dev/input/js".

Identify the device like this:

```
import evdev
devices = [evdev.InputDevice(path) for path in evdev.list_devices()]
for device in devices:
    print(device.path, device.name)
```

Or if there is only one, just use the first one that comes along.

```
import evdev
gamepad = evdev.InputDevice( evdev.list_devices()[0] )
```